# Интеграция Atom и GitHub нативными инструментами

Tags: git, github, atom

Приветствую. Имеется редактор Atom, у него - нативная работа с GitHub. Но вопрос: как опубликовать репозиторий на ГитХабе? Авторизации нет, ничего нет.

Вкладка I:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вкладка II:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: заходите на гитхаб, создаете новый репозиторий, и гитхаб сам пишет, как "опубликовать" Ваш код (git origin add && git push). А чем Вы пользуетесь на своей стороне - ему побоку.

Comment: Дак а как подключить этот репозиторий к Atom?

Comment: atom сам подтянет Ваш репозиторий, как только вы его добавите. А для этого Вам атом не нужен.

Comment: То есть, мне надо через какой-нибудь Github Desktop или иной клиент этот репозиторий подгрузить, задать его в Атоме и он его подтянет?

Comment: Через консоль Гита добавьте и скорее всего все само и подымется